# How to extract certain strings when they occur adjacently with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing an HTML page's result from BeautifulSoup and the part(s) I'm interested in looks like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-circle align-middle font-80" style="color: #45C414; margin-right: 15px"></i>Departure for <a href="/en/ais/details/ports/17787/port_name:TEKIRDAG/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: TEKIRDAG">TEKIRDAG</a> </td>
```

I'm interested in extracting the `port_name`, TEKIRDAG, however there are many port name's that are labeled identically. My question is is there a way to only extract `port_name` if it occers after the string `'Departure for'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can locate the text node and get the [next sibling](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: data = """<i class="fa fa-circle align-middle font-80" style="color: #45C414; margin-right: 15px"></i>Departu
   ...: re for <a href="/en/ais/details/ports/17787/port_name:TEKIRDAG/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="Vie
   ...: w details for: TEKIRDAG">TEKIRDAG</a> </td>"""
   ...:     

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

In [4]: soup.find(text="Departure for ").next_sibling.get_text()
Out[4]: u'TEKIRDAG'
```

Comment: Perfect! Quick follow up: how could I tweak this if there were multiple occurrences? Sorry, I neglected to mention in my question that I want to iterate through to collect all the `port_name`'s.

Comment: @345243lkj sure, use `find_all(text="Departure for ")` to locate all "labels" and then call `next_sibling` for every label found.